# Curl PHP http_code return 0 but browser return 200

Tags: php, curl

This is happens with PHP curl.

My code looks like

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms?username=xxxxx&password=xxxx&to=xxxxx&text=Dear&from=STLTD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_exec($ch);
```

If i run URL from browser than it will send the SMS and return http_code 200 but when i used cURL it's return http_code 0.

Output of curl_getinfo($ch);

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&to=xxx&text=Dear&from=STLTD
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 160
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 20.035848
    [namelookup_time] => 5.019469
    [connect_time] => 5.02008
    [pretransfer_time] => 5.020088
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 20.035834
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: When you execute the URL from browser, does it print the entire array?

Comment: check error `echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);`

Comment: `error codes: 0: ok the operation was successful.` se the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay : From browser Get response "Sent"  and Status Code is 200 OK.

Comment: @VipulSolanki: I tried the curl_error and it respond "Empty reply from server".

Comment: `[http_code] => 0` means `ok the operation was successful`.  read doc here... http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: It helps to you for Call URL using GET. [http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-get.php](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-get.php)